# How to populate chart with sql query that depends on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, charts

I have a asp.net page in which I have a chart that I dragged on from the toolbox designer. I know that if I click on this chart, a "chart tasks" menu will appear so that I can define the sql data source, chart type and x&y values. The problem I am having is that my sql data source requires user input. I want the user to input a date and search records based on the input date. Therefore, I cant define an sql query on the chart tasks menu because it will tell me that my query is invalid. My code looks like this so far:

```
con1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand (string.Format ("select CustomerName, AccountNumber,  DateReading, Time, ID from dbo.NewLogTable join dbo.CustomerTable on ID = Customer_ID join dbo.VoltageTable on Voltage_Reading = Provided_Voltage where Sensor_ID = 'FA0009' and DateReading= '{0}' " ,TextBox1.Text), con1);
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    da2.Fill(ds2);
    Chart2.DataSource = da2;
    Chart2.Visible = true;
    Chart2.DataBind();

    con1.Close();
```

whenever I input the date and click the button, nothing happens. I know the sqlCommand is correct. However, I can not find a way to set the x and y values for my chart. I tried `Chart2.Xvalue` and .parameters and cant find a way to set those. I think that is whats giving me trouble. Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

You have to assign **DataSet ds2 as DataSource** for your chart instead of using SqlDataAdapter da2.

```
Chart2.DataSource = ds2;
```

instead of

```
Chart2.DataSource = da2;
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I see the change you have made and it makes sense. However, I still don't have a way to set my x & y parameters. Also, I am still not even seeing my graph even though I have set visible to true.

Comment: @Rick once you have assigned the datasource, you need to Databind() it for the data to display.  Hope this helps.